# How can two Components subscribe to the same Event?

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I have a *Client* service with an array *"messages"* that contains server messages. Then I have a component that subscribes to that array and checks every new message for its subject.

Like this:

```
client.messages.subscribe(msg => {
  switch (msg.SUBJECT)
  {
    case 'SOME_TEXT':
      //some code;
      break;
    default:
      console.log(msg);
      break;
  }
                                 });
```

However when I subscribe second component to that array with the same code *(the only difference being the subjects in the switch)*, only the switch of the first component is executed.

**Second component never gets the message.**

Codes should be correct. The message is only received by component that is first in the project tree.

As you requested code for ClientService, here it is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const CHAT_URL = //MY IP AND PORT;



export interface Message {
  SUBJECT: string;
  NAME?: string;
  ROOMS?: string[];
  //plus many others, some are strings, some numbers
}

@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
  public messages: Subject < Message > ;
  constructor(wsService: WebsocketService) {
    this.messages = < Subject < Message >> wsService
      .connect(CHAT_URL).pipe(
        map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
          console.log(response);
          const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
          return data;
      }));
  }
```

And here is my WebSocketService that is used above.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, Observer } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {
  constructor() {}

  private subject: Subject < MessageEvent > ;

  public connect(url): Subject < MessageEvent > {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(url);
      console.log('Successfully connected: ' + url);
    }
    return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url): Subject < MessageEvent > {
    const ws = new WebSocket(url);
    const observable = Observable.create(
      (obs: Observer < MessageEvent > ) => {
        ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
        ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
        ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
        return ws.close.bind(ws);
      });
    const observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      }
    };
    return Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }

}
```

Comment: How is `messages` declared and used inside client service?

Comment: show your code for `messages`

Comment: please show your service's code.

Comment: @GCSDC I updated the post with ClientService.

Comment: @Austaras You can now find it in ClientService under Injectable part

Comment: @Ala It is up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a share() operator to ClientService see if it works

```
  this.messages = < Subject < Message >> wsService
      .connect(CHAT_URL).pipe(
        map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
          console.log(response);
          const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
          return data;
      }),share());
```

Comment: This was it. I imported { share } from 'rxjs/operators' and added it into the pipe like in your answer. Thank you.